# Eclipse RCP: Create a file inside the plugin location

Tags: eclipse, file, plugins, rcp

I'm trying to add a simple text file into a plugin at runtime but I don't know how to continue.

I know how to check if a file exists and how I can access it but I can't figure out how to create one.

If the file "data.txt" under "webapps/masks/data.txt" already exists then I can access it with the getEntry() function.

```
URL url = Platform.getBundle(MyPlugin.PLUGIN_ID).getEntry("webapps/masks/data.txt");
```

If the file data.txt doesn't exist the url will be null, how do I create data.txt in the next step?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can't create a file in a deployed plugin.

Comment: I was trying to create a simple text file (RSS Feed) and write periodically to it. I understood now that using jars is not the right approach. The issue I had was that the text file is used by the webserver of my plugin, so I couldn't use files external to the plugin as web documents. Note: The solution is in the first answer to this post, I answered it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Since I read that it is not possible to manipulate files directly inside of a jar file without exracting everything, making the change and packaging it again I decided to NOT pack the plugin at all.

This can be done by adding the following  header to the MANIFEST file of the corresponding plugin: Eclipse-BundleShape: dir

This tells eclipse to use a directory structure for the generated plugin instead of a jar file. Now the file data.txt can be easily manipualted via simple file operations.

Comment: This can work for your specific installation, it won't work if your plugin is ever installed read-only